# Create responsive Qooxdoo HBox layout where widgets don't show without enough space

Tags: qooxdoo

How can I create with Qooxdoo a user resizeable `Window` where the content is made out of a few widgets (e.g. `Label`s) where the display of some is disabled when the space isn't enough?

**Example:**
I have the three labels "unimportant" (right aligned), "very important" (left aligned) and "must have" (right) in the `HBox`. Any extra space should go just right of the left most label to keep the alignment requirements.
In ASCII art this would look like:

```
--------------------------------------------------------
|very important|                 |unimportant|must have|
--------------------------------------------------------

-----------------------------------------------
|very important|        |unimportant|must have|
-----------------------------------------------

--------------------------------------
|very important|unimportant|must have|
--------------------------------------

-------------------------------
|very important|    |must have|
-------------------------------
                                         <-- making the window smaller
--------------------------
|very important|must have|
--------------------------

-------------------
|       |must have|
-------------------

-----------
|must have|
-----------
```

The minimal width of the Window would be the space that "must have" requires.

**Bonus question:** the "unimportant" would actually be a label for "must have" which can be a widget that takes more vertical space. So both should be centered to each other, something that an `Atom` with those two might be normally used for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't like implementation but it does work as intended:

```
const mainBar = new qx.ui.container.Composite(new qx.ui.layout.HBox());

// sub bar for right and center labels
const subBar = new qx.ui.container.Composite(new qx.ui.layout.HBox());
subBar.setMinWidth(0);// this line is important

// left static label
const left = new qx.ui.basic.Atom("very important");
subBar.add(left);

// center label has a minor priority
const center = new qx.ui.container.Composite(new qx.ui.layout.HBox());
const dummy = new qx.ui.basic.Atom();
center.add(dummy, {flex: 1});
const centerLabel = new qx.ui.basic.Atom("unimportant");
center.add(centerLabel);
subBar.add(center, {flex: 1});
mainBar.add(subBar, {flex: 1});

const right = new qx.ui.form.Button("must have");
mainBar.add(right);

const win = new qx.ui.window.Window().set({width: 600, height: 100});
win.setLayout(new qx.ui.layout.Grow());
win.add(mainBar);
win.setUseResizeFrame(false);
win.open();

const defaultLeftWidth = left.getSizeHint().width;
const defaultCenterWidth = center.getSizeHint().width;
win.addListener("resize", function(){
  this.info(center.getBounds().width, defaultCenterWidth);
  if (center.getBounds().width <= defaultCenterWidth){
    centerLabel.setVisibility("hidden");
  } else {
    centerLabel.setVisibility("visible");
  }
  
  if (subBar.getBounds().width < defaultLeftWidth){
    left.setVisibility("hidden");
  } else {
    left.setVisibility("visible");
  }
}, this);

// Document is the application root
const doc = this.getRoot();

// Add button to document at fixed coordinates
doc.add(win,
{
  left : 100,
  top  : 50
  
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort. But apart from the missing alignment (I tried to make it more clear in the description above) your solution doesn't have the "pop in"/"pop out" of the labels depending on the space available.

Comment: Edited, under pop in / pop out you mean an animation? Now it just appears and disappears.